# check if user signed in with phone number or email and password in firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to check in the flutter app if the user has signed in with email and password or with phone number?

we can do something like this to check if the user signedIn in general

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasData){

..........

or 
 if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null){
            
      }
```

But I want to know if the user has signed in with his phone number or with email and password.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem for now by adding aditional conditions to the stream builder

```
body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if (snapshot.hasData && FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber == null){
      return  VerifyEmailPage();
    } else if (snapshot.hasData && FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber != null){
      return const HomeScreen();
    }
    else {
      return AuthPage();
    }
  },
),
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to do it but this is what I came up with for the moment.